# Writing a loop that works for any value of N

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a code for a 1D heat equation. Im trying to format a `for` loop so that the `A` matrix will follow a certain pattern of `1 -2 1` down the entire diagonal of a matrix that could be infinite. The pattern starts to take shape when I mess around with the initialized count at the beginning of the `for` loop but this changes the size of the matrix which fails the rest of the code.

My current code is below. The commented `A` matrix edits are what it should be.

```
N = 5;

%A(2,1:3) = [1 -2 1];
%A(3,2:4) = [1 -2 1];
%A(4,3:5) = [1 -2 1];
%A(5,4:6) = [1 -2 1];

A = zeros(N+1,N+1);
A(1,1) = 1;
for count=N:N+1    
    A(count+1,count:count+2) = [1 -2 1];
end
A(N+1,N+1) = 1;
```

Comment: I don't understand why, `k= 0.2;`. Also could you simplify the qustion and add comments to tell what do **YOU** want to do in a particular line? May be, give your expected output. What is the output of this program now? Also, `x` will be a 6 element array. `A` will be `6X6` but for loop tries to access something like `A(7,8)`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab you can often avoid loops. In this case you can get the desired result with 2D convolution:

```
>> N = 6;
>> A = [1 zeros(1,N-1); conv2(eye(N-2), [1 -2 1]); zeros(1,N-1) 1]
A =
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1    -2     1     0     0     0
     0     1    -2     1     0     0
     0     0     1    -2     1     0
     0     0     0     1    -2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Or, depending on what you want,

```
>> A = conv2(eye(N), [1 -2 1], 'same')
A =
    -2     1     0     0     0     0
     1    -2     1     0     0     0
     0     1    -2     1     0     0
     0     0     1    -2     1     0
     0     0     0     1    -2     1
     0     0     0     0     1    -2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many simple ways of creating this matrix.

1. Your loop can be amended as follows:

   ```
   N = 5;
   A = zeros(N+1,N+1);
   A(1,1) = 1;
   for row = 2:N
      A(row, row-1:row+1) = [1 -2 1];
   end
   A(N+1,N+1) = 1;
   ```

   I've renamed `count` to `row`, we're indexing each row (from 2 to `N`, skipping the first and last rows), then finding with `row-1:row+1` the three indices for that row that you want to address.
2. Directly indexing the diagonal and off-diagonal elements. Diagonal elements for an `N`x`N` matrix are `1:N+1:end`. This is obviously more complex, I'd prefer the loop:

   ```
   N = 6;
   A = zeros(N,N);
   A(1:N+1:end) = -2;
   A(2:N+1:end-2*N) = 1; % skip last row
   A(2*N+2:N+1:end) = 1; % skip first row
   A(1,1) = 1;
   A(N,N) = 1;
   ```
3. Using `diag`. We need to special-case the first and last rows:

   ```
   N = 6;
   A = diag(-2*ones(N,1),0) + diag(ones(N-1,1),1) + diag(ones(N-1,1),-1);
   A(1,1:2) = [1,0];
   A(end,end-1:end) = [0,1];
   ```